# Center marker after resize using javascript tabs

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I have a problem centering the marker for a google map I have on site.

The map is in a javascript tab and is triggered to resize after activating the tab so that it will reload and appear, thus:

```
<li>
                <a href="#" class="button tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'contact');resetMap();"><span class="topnavlinks">Contact</span></a>
            </li>

function resetMap() {
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

It'll reset to size, but just like I've read in countless places it won't reset to centre the marker. I have tried various answers that I've managed to find but still cannot find a solution to this problem!

My tabs code:

```
<script><!-- tabs -->
  function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

And my map code (just without the styles):

```
function initMap() {
  var theoneway = {lat: 9.700082, lng: 100.02203};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: theoneway
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: theoneway,
    map: map
  });
}
```

And finally the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="map" style="height:500px;"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(mykeyishere)&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</div>
```

A working version can be found here: http://theoneway.asia/bench/

I hope that's enough information, and I massively appreciate any help and advice!

Comment: Reinit the map on choosing the contact page.

Comment: I thought I was already doing that with the trigger function? And this works fine, it reinits the map, just doesn't center the marker.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this with the listen event in my map js file in case anyone else has this same issue:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center); 
});
```